# RarCrack installation issues

Tags: installation, permissions

I'm pretty new to Linux. 
I currently operate on Ubuntu 10.04 Desktop.
Anyhow, a while ago while being slightly intoxicated I have encrypted a .rar file with a password and deleted the original files. I now really want to get these files back so I have downloaded the latest release of rarcrack (0.2).

I cannot seem to install it!
Here's what happens when I go to the rarcarck-0.2 folder and type "make" as indicated on their website.

```
root@linux:~/rarcrack-0.2# make
gcc -pthread rarcrack.c `xml2-config --libs --cflags` -O2 -o rarcrack
/bin/sh: xml2-config: not found
In file included from rarcrack.c:21:
rarcrack.h:25:48: error: libxml/xmlmemory.h: No such file or directory
rarcrack.h:26:27: error: libxml/parser.h: No such file or directory
rarcrack.h:27:36: error: libxml/parserInternals.h: No such file or directory
rarcrack.h:28:25: error: libxml/tree.h: No such file or directory
rarcrack.h:29:28: error: libxml/threads.h: No such file or directory
rarcrack.c:30: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘pwdMutex’
rarcrack.c:33: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘status’
rarcrack.c:35: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘finishedMutex’
rarcrack.c: In function ‘savestatus’:
rarcrack.c:46: error: ‘xmlNodePtr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
rarcrack.c:46: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
rarcrack.c:46: error: for each function it appears in.)
rarcrack.c:46: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘root’
rarcrack.c:47: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘node’
rarcrack.c:48: error: ‘xmlChar’ undeclared (first use in this function)
rarcrack.c:48: error: ‘tmp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
rarcrack.c:49: error: ‘status’ undeclared (first use in this function)
rarcrack.c:50: error: ‘root’ undeclared (first use in this function)
rarcrack.c:52: error: ‘finishedMutex’ undeclared (first use in this function)
rarcrack.c:53: error: ‘node’ undeclared (first use in this function)
rarcrack.c:55: error: ‘pwdMutex’ undeclared (first use in this function)
rarcrack.c:56: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘xmlChar’
rarcrack.c:66: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘xmlChar’
rarcrack.c: In function ‘loadstatus’:
rarcrack.c:87: error: ‘xmlNodePtr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
rarcrack.c:87: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘root’
rarcrack.c:88: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘node’
rarcrack.c:89: error: ‘xmlParserCtxtPtr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
rarcrack.c:89: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘parserctxt’
rarcrack.c:96: error: ‘status’ undeclared (first use in this function)
rarcrack.c:99: error: ‘root’ undeclared (first use in this function)
rarcrack.c:103: error: ‘parserctxt’ undeclared (first use in this function)
rarcrack.c:104: error: ‘node’ undeclared (first use in this function)
rarcrack.c:108: error: ‘XML_SUBSTITUTE_BOTH’ undeclared (first use in this function)
rarcrack.c:127: error: ‘finishedMutex’ undeclared (first use in this function)
rarcrack.c: In function ‘nextpass’:
rarcrack.c:170: error: ‘pwdMutex’ undeclared (first use in this function)
rarcrack.c: In function ‘status_thread’:
rarcrack.c:182: error: ‘finishedMutex’ undeclared (first use in this function)
rarcrack.c:188: error: ‘pwdMutex’ undeclared (first use in this function)
rarcrack.c: In function ‘crack_thread’:
rarcrack.c:206: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
rarcrack.c:208: error: ‘finishedMutex’ undeclared (first use in this function)
rarcrack.c:205: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fgets’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
rarcrack.c: In function ‘init’:
rarcrack.c:250: error: ‘pwdMutex’ undeclared (first use in this function)
rarcrack.c:251: error: ‘finishedMutex’ undeclared (first use in this function)
rarcrack.c:283: warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘char (*)[300]’
rarcrack.c:317: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
rarcrack.c: In function ‘main’:
rarcrack.c:351: error: ‘status’ undeclared (first use in this function)
rarcrack.c:353: error: ‘pwdMutex’ undeclared (first use in this function)
rarcrack.c:354: error: ‘finishedMutex’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

And here's what happens when I type "make install".

```
root@linux:~/rarcrack-0.2# make install
install -s rarcrack /usr/bin/bin
install: cannot stat `rarcrack': No such file or directory
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

ANY help would be VERY appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The likely problem is that you need to install `libxml2-dev` (`sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev`) to get the necessary headers.

Answer (score 2):

Installing with 10.04 is also quite possible. There seemed to be only 1 extra requirement, at least on my laptop. On command line run `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev` to install library named `libxml2-dev`, and then run `make` etc.

Answer (score 1):

So you are new to linux and work with Ubuntu 10.04? Actual version is 13.04. Your problems might result from missing or outdated packages. When compiling, the program doesn't find that Information.

Upgrading your system will be the best solution for a lot of problems, you will run in soon. I'm not sure though, if you can do that over the update manager, because 10.04, although Long Term Suppport LTS, isn't supported any longer (since May 2013). Actual LTS is 12.04.

Open your update manager, which should be in Applications - Administration or - System. I don' t remember as I work with Unity. Then look if there is an item saying "Update to new Version". If it is 10.10, then I would recommend to download actual version and replace the old system.

If your Hardware is also outdated, then you should consider installing Lubuntu, which is a lightweight version of Ubuntu.

http://lubuntu.net/

Then compile and install missing packages, if that's the case.

Comment: I have now done a clean install of Ubuntu 12.04 as suggested. Downloaded same .tar.gz2 package, here's the outcome.

me77ow@linux:~/Downloads/rarcrack-0.2$ make
gcc -pthread rarcrack.c `xml2-config --libs --cflags` -O2 -o rarcrack
/bin/sh: 1: xml2-config: not found
In file included from rarcrack.c:21:0:
rarcrack.h:25:48: fatal error: libxml/xmlmemory.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [all] Error 1

Comment: Here are the files that I have extracted from the tar.bz2 package.

CHANGELOG  Makefile    rarcrack.h  README.html    test.7z   test.zip
LICENSE    rarcrack.c  README      RELEASE_NOTES  test.rar

And here is the source of Makefile:
CC=gcc
PREFIX=/usr
DOCDIR=${PREFIX}/share/doc/rarcrack

all:
 ${CC} -pthread rarcrack.c `xml2-config --libs --cflags` -O2 -o rarcrack
clean:
 -rm *.o rarcrack
install:
 install -s rarcrack ${PREFIX}/bin
 -mkdir -p ${DOCDIR}
 chmod 755 ${DOCDIR}
 install -m 644 -t ${DOCDIR} CHANGELOG LICENSE README README.html RELEASE_NOTES
uninstall:
 -rm ${PREFIX}/bin/rarcrack

Comment: Install gcc if it is not installed. Install Synaptic. Install nautilus-open-terminal from SC or Synaptic. Install libxml++2.6.x. Install libxml2. Install libxml2-dev. Open terminal and type "nautilus -q". Close terminal. In nautilus go into extracted folder. Right click and select open in terminal. Terminal should open in your folder. Type "make". Wait. Type "sudo make install". Enter password. Programm should install now. Read readme-file for use. Basically it is rarcrack file.zip, run it in terminal inside folder where zip-files are. It didn't work for me, although it installed correctly.

Comment: ok. Finally I got it working. You have to specify type of zip with type parameter. For example "rarcrack abc.zip --type zip".

Comment: Nice to know, that programs like this exist. Use it carefully!

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! Worked a like a charm. I appreciate your help enormously!